# How do I include WordPress PHP tags in JSON-LD?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I want to add JSON-LD structured data to my WordPress WooCommerce site in order to increase my chances of rich snippets on search engine results pages.

I want to begin by adding it first to my products pages.

If I've included the code below in header-shop.php...

```
    <!-- Include Schema Markup File
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<?php include('json-ld.php'); ?><script type="application/ld+json"><?php echo json_encode($payload); ?></script>
```

how do I reference PHP tags like `<php the_title(); ?>` within the json-ld.php file?

Is it as simple as the following?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "<?php the_title(); ?>",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
   ],
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.4",
    "ratingCount": "89"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "119.99",
    "highPrice": "199.99",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend you to make an PHP array/Object with all the data you want. Then, use `json_encode` to render the minified JSON. Also, use the `wp_head` hook. About the WP tags, all the `the_` tags have an `get_the_` version. Inspect the WP function and you will see what function is called.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Maxwells.c! Where would I put the PHP array? in json-ld.php? within the javascript tags? Or outside of them? Or do I not even need the javascript tags/script? How do I ensure that the ouput is properly rendered JSON-LD? And what exactly would I need in it? The tags? And/or do I need to use the `get_the_` functions versus tags?Is there any way you could include some code examples of what you're suggesting?

Comment: Many questions. First of all, i suggest you to look to an JSON-LD plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-structuring-markup/) and check if it solves your problem. About the `get_the_` functions, you use them when you don't want to output the data, just get the data. After checking the plugin i can explain what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in PHP to print to your page. By echoing your script in entirety will allow you to concat inline functions.

```
echo '
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "'. the_title() .'",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
   ],
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "ACME"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.4",
    "ratingCount": "89"
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "lowPrice": "119.99",
    "highPrice": "199.99",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  }
}
</script>
';
```

Comment: This is brilliantly simple! Thanks so much @ProEvilz!

Answer (score 2):

For Articles, here is what I use (guess it's not gonna be very complicated to adapt it for Products):

```
    function add_ld_json()
    {
        // get post thumbnail
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'post-full');
    
        // get canonical
        $post_full_url = wp_get_canonical_url();
    
        // get title
        $page_h1 = the_title('', '', false);
    
        // create ld-json with structured data
        $ld_json = <<< EOT
    
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "https://schema.org/",
            "@type": "TechArticle",
            "mainEntityOfPage": {
                "@type": "WebPage",
                "@id": "{$post_full_url}"
            },
            "headline": "{$page_h1}",
            "image": "{$thumb[0]}",
            "author": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "your-organization-name"
            }
        }
        </script>
    EOT;
    
        echo "{$ld_json}";
    }
```

Then, you have to include this in your header.php or wherever your page code is. I also exclude 404 pages and the front page (it doesn't make much sense for those pages) with this condition:

```
if (!is_front_page() and !is_404())
add_action('wp_head', 'add_ld_json', -1);
```

It is recommended to include ld-json in head before all the other meta tags like title/description etc.